# Not getting the value of query string in express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to get the value of the query string `term=+ e.target.value`
in the server but it's not showing up. Tried to write the route as `'/doSomeSearch?term'` and still no `req.query.term` doesn't show any value in the server. 
I changed the header from json to  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' but only get 404 error back. Is the route not correct?

Input.js

```
handleInputBox (e) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/searchItems?term='+ e.target.value, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers:{
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
      },
        ).then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
             response.json().then(json => {
               console.log("yes")
             });
            }else{
              console.log("no")
            }
          }
      ); 
   }
};
```

Server.js(Express)

```
app.get('/doSomeSearch?', function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.query)
})
```

Comment: Why do you put the question mark in the path? It's a delimiter. But in `some/path?term` the query parameter doesn't actually have a value.

Comment: when we are querying, should we not use `?`

Comment: I thought i was sending the value using 'http://localhost:3000/searchItems?term='+ e.target.value` through e.target.value. then what is the right way of doing it?

Comment: `"searchItems" !== "doSomeSearch"` and `?` isn't actually part of the *route*. Give a [mcve]. What's the actual URL you're hitting; is the problem that your frontend is generating the wrong URL (in which case the Express code is irrelevant) or your server has the wrong behaviour for the right URL (in which case the fetch is)?

Comment: should it not be `app.post`  or the method in fetch should be `get`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the routes should be POST method. As your are hitting a POST method type api and you have GET method configured, express cannot find the signature and return 404.

```
app.post('/doSomeSearch?', function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.query)
})
```

This should fix the issue. Hope it helps :)